# Generate an URL to different portlet in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

Currently I generate an URL to a different portlet in this fashion:

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL var="custom" portletName="portlet2_WAR_portlet2">
   <portlet:param name="action" value="advanced"/>
   <portlet:param name="value" value="321"/>
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>
```

the most important part is the `portletName` argument. I build it just like they said on  [Liferay's page](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Inter-portlet+communication). The problem is, that manually creating a `portletName` is horrible. Just imagine a typo, a change of the name...

So my question is: is there an utility class, jsp tag (or alike) that is capable of automatically creating a valid portlet name (given some info from the programmer, e.g. the name of the portlet).

One thing: my portlets are singletons, so no *INSTANCE* param is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to get the correct portlet name, you must have its id.

Liferay provides `com.liferay.portal.service.PortletLocalServiceUtil` service util class and method `getPortletById(String id)`. This will give you `com.liferay.portal.model.Portlet` object and from method `getPortletName()`, you will get the portlet name.

The IDs of the builtin portlets are available in the com.liferay.portal.util.PortletKeys, so, you dont have to hardocde the IDs (at least for the built in portlets).

Comment: But again can't we make a typo with the ID? ;-)

Comment: You need to provide atleast something :), typo you can do in anything! :D, to err is human! :). But, to get the portlet ids of the built in portlets, there is one interface/class which holds Enum of the portlet name and ids, will let you know once I get it

Comment: Got it, please use com.liferay.portal.util.PortletKeys, this holds mapping of portlet class and ids. So, now for built in portlet, you dont have to hard code, you will have from PortletKeys.BLOGS or anything and you will get an id, from that id, you will get the Portlet object and so on. Accept the truth (as an answer)

Comment: And for my own portlets, i need to specify the key that is set in `<portlet-name>` in `portlet.xml` ?

Comment: Yes, it is your id, so you can have your own PortletKeys for your project, so that in future, you do not have to hard code it.

Comment: But the method takes a `long` and that name is a `String`. Also please note, that currently I have a nice JSP tag and I dont want to start mixing Java code with my layouts... So how can I use the mentioned classes?

Comment: getPortletById() takes String, and as far the jsp tag is concerned, you can create custom tag to fetch the portlet based on id.

Comment: My mistake. Well, still, I get null ptrs though I call the method with the value put in `<portlet-name>`. So I can only ask: does the method `getPortletName` return a string that is compatible with the `portletName` attribute of the JSP tag?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12783/discussion-between-felix-christy-and-queequeg)

Comment: Guys, it looks like you haven't come to a conclusion even in the chat. But the problem seems pretty easy: getPortletById() takes the portlet ID, in the same way as the tag's portletName attribute does. And the ID is nothing more than a fully qualified name = "<portlet-name> + the war suffix".

Comment: Even more importantly, I think the answer to the original question should be NO, no such utility is available.

Answer (score 3):

Portlet names hardly change, even liferay uses a constant class ([`PortletKeys.java`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/util/PortletKeys.html)) to store the portlet Ids and uses it frequently.

Its like the primary key for a portlet, if it changes that may mean it is a new portlet.

So if your portlet depends on a third party portlet and then the ID/name of the portlet changes then I don't see any other way but to change your code to match that.

If there is another good way of doing it, then I will also be glad to know it.

Comment: you providing answer or comment? :)